# mouse input for x and y point to create a line using line equation algorithm (open gl)

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, draw, equation

I need to create line using the line equation algorithm where the value of x1,y1 and x2,y2 is via mouse input. here's my long long coding -

```
#include <stdio.h>;
#include <GL/glut.h>;

int counter;
int x1, x2;
int y1, y2;

void setPixel(int x, int y)
{
    float m;
    float b;
    float x3, y3;

    x3 = x2-x1;
    y3 = y2-y1;

    if(counter==1)
    {
        glPointSize(9.0f);
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);

        m = y3 / x3;

        while(x1 <= x2)
        {
            b =  y - (m*x2);
            y = (m*x1)+b;
            y = 400-y;
            glVertex2i(x1,y);
            x1++;

        }

        glEnd();
        glFlush();
    }

}
void myMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{

    if(button ==  GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN )
    {

        setPixel(x,y);
        counter++;

        if(counter==0)
        { 
            x1 = x;
            y1 = y;

        }
        if(counter==1)

        { 
            x2 = x;
            y2 = y;

        }
    }
}

void myKeyboardAct(unsigned char c, int x, int y)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case 's' : //show coordinates' x and y

            printf("what where and what are x and y %d %d \n" ,x,y);
            printf("what where and what are x and y %d %d \n" ,x2,y2);

            break;

        case 'e' : //flush and draw

            glFlush();
            break;
    }
}

void myDisplay(void)
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glColor3f(200.0,0.00,0);
    gluOrtho2D(-300.0,300.0,-200.0,200.0);
    //gluOrtho2D(0.0,600.0,400.0, 0.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutMouseFunc(myMouse);

    glFlush();

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInitWindowSize(600,400);
    //glutInitWindowSize(1024,800);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutCreateWindow("HELLO THERE YOU CAN JUST DRAW AWAYYYY DRAW       AWAAAAAYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY");
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutKeyboardFunc(myKeyboardAct);
    glutMainLoop ();
    return 0;
}
```

however, the problem ive encountered is that the line seems to appear a few points above or a few points below from where i've clicked. another thing is that if the gradient is negative, the line will not appear.

Comment: Your code sample is quite long.  Have you thought of narrowing the problem to one section and just showing us that one?

Comment: Try stepping through the code with a debugger. One thing that jumps out is that you're only incrementing `counter`, and have a `counter == 0` test after you increment it. It could never be 0 there. And the `counter == 1` test would only be true the very first time you enter that code.

Comment: @La-comadreja sorry about that, but i'm not sure where's the error as my lecturer gave us hints that about how to do it.

Comment: @RetoKoradi oh yes, i'm sorry ive updated the counter == 1 and counter ==2 , it doesnt do much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first test if you obtain the correct coordinates from mouse.

- so draw some cross on those points
- so you actually see if there is not some offset between mouse and cross.
- try this also after you resize your window (unless it is full-screen).

You call setPixel() before you copy mouse position to your points !!! try it like this:

```
void myMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
 {
 if(button ==  GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN )
  {
  if(counter==0) { x1=x; y1=y; counter++; }
  if(counter==1) { x2=x; y2=y; }      
  setPixel(x,y);
  }
 }
```

**Your Draw line has many bugs, it is an assigment so I will not repair it just give you hints**

- why to call it setPixel(x,y) ? when it draws a line

  - **also what is x,y when you use x1,y1,x2,y2 as input points**
  - this is why your line is bugged !!!
- why x3,y3 not call dx,dy so it is more readable for others?
- **you are destroying x1 !!!**

  - therefore after another click/setPixel call you will lost your line
- you always use x as main axis (if |dx|<|dy| then you will have holes in your line)
- **you always increment x1++ what if x1>x2 ?**

  - either swap (x1,y1) with (x2,y2)
  - or instead of x1++ use x1+=dir ... and set direction to +/-1 according to the x1 < x2
- you compute b constant in each pixel why ? move it before loop
- **why y=400-y ?**

  - should not you use screen y-size instead ?
  - if your OpenGL screen height is not 400px then it will generate offset !!!

Comment: thank  you for your hints. truth is the main coding was given to me by my lecturer, so what i did was use what he gave and edit it step by step. there are a lot of the things that you asked that have been modified by my lecturer, without giving me clear explanation, even when i asked he seemed a little anxious to answer. he did this coding in the lab and it was okay, but when i run it at my laptop the errors surfaced. anyhow thank you, i'll try my best on my own first with your hints!